# Cookies deletion, can someone help to rectify code below?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I don't know what I am doing wrong here when trying to delete cookie... can someone help?   Here is code which I am trying to delete cookie.

```
if (Request.Cookies["RememberUser"] != null)
{  
    HttpCookie objCookie = Request.Cookies["RememberUser"];
    objCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);                        
    Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie);
}
```

Is above code is right to delete cookie, for some reason this is not working...

This code is not working even when I tried to update cookies with
`Response.Cookies.Set(objCookie);`.

Comment: in msdn it used "new HttpCookie("UserSettings");" instead of "request.cookies....  ;"

Comment: nope that is not the case.  I mean i tried exactly like it is mentioned in MSDN, don't what is wrong here.

Comment: @alirizaadiyahsi this code doesn't working.  **HttpCookie objCookie = new HttpCookie("RememberUser");
 objCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
 Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above code is worked.i'm surprising why you can't delete.the problem may be appear in your create cookie code.

```
    var cookie = this.Request.Cookies["user"];
    if (cookie == null)
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("user");
        cookie.Path = "/";
        cookie.Value = "123";
        this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    else
    {
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

the first time access with no cookie and response header from server.

Response Headers:

```
Date: Sun, 08 Apr 2012 02:18:37 GMT

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

Set-Cookie: user=123; path=/
```

access again with cookie and response header from server.

Response Headers:

```
Date: Sun, 08 Apr 2012 02:19:32 GMT

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

Set-Cookie: user=123; expires=Sat, 07-Apr-2012 02:19:32 GMT; path=/
```

and Request Headers:

```
GET /
Cookie: user=123
.....
```

you can use `firebug` with firefox or the `fiddler` software to tracking response and request and see why can't delete cookie.good luck.